# The deeper meaning of "not enough coffee yet on my end"

Tags: meaning, phrase-meaning

What's the deeper meaning of this phrase?

> not enough coffee yet on my end

Comment: Without context, this doesn't convey anything at all, never mind a "deeper" meaning.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Usually, if you hear this phrase in a professional setting or in a casual conversation, the literal meaning is that the speaker needs more caffeine in order to function properly.

It is a way of explaining that they feel tired or that they are not performing as well as they could at the moment. That is to say, if they go get a fresh cup of coffee, they will feel more refreshed. The phrase is most often used as an excuse for some minor failing, often in the morning.

> A: Did you send me that email yet? I don't see anything in my inbox.
>   B: Yes, I sent it to you just 5 minutes ago.
>   A: Oh, I see it now. Sorry, *not enough coffee on my end*.

Often, the "*on my end*" part if omitted, reducing the phrase to just "*not enough coffee*".

Comment: Unless of course it’s two people pouring coffee through a big funnel in order to fill, say, a large vat. The person pouring the coffee asks, “How’s it looking down there? Are we close?”. The person holding the other end of the funnel into the vat replies, “Nope, not enough coffee yet on my end, still needs more!” Another example of why context is always important in questions. ;-)

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet I think in that context the meaning is pretty obvious, and there's no 'deeper' meaning. That's definitely a good point, though.